# using isNan() function to pass parameter to javascript from html and check value then return value

Tags: javascript, html

I am basically trying to get a user entered value to be checked and confirmed that it is a number between 10 & 100, once confirmed store into the variable 'num2' - thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <script type ="text/javascript">
    <!--
      function numcheck(pass) {
      var num2 =0;
      isNan()= numcheck(pass);

    if (isNan() == true)
    {
    alert("You can only enter a number in the text field");
    }
    else if (isNan() <=10 || isNan(p) >=100)
    {
    alert ("You must enter a number between 10 and 100");
    }
    else
    num2 = inNan();
    alert ("You have entered var2" + "which has now been stored, thankyou");
    return num2;
     -->
    </script>
    Number: <input type = “text” name = “numcheck” />
    <button onClick="numcheck();"/> Enter </button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  While quickly looking over your question, I noticed a few things. Are you referring to `isNaN()`?  JavaScript is case sensitive.  Also, to check whether something is NaN (not a number), you need to supply an argument to the function, e.g. `isNaN(1)`, or `isNaN('e')`.

Comment: Whatever resource you are using to learn js, you need to immediately stop using it and try something else.  It's hard to imagine how you could have come up with that code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <header>
   <script>
  function numcheck() {
  var var2 = document.getElementById('num').value;

       if (isNaN(var2)){
        alert("You can only enter a number in the text field");
        document.getElementById('num').value = "";
        }
        else if ( var2 <=10 || var2 >=100){
        alert ("You must enter a number between 10 and 100");
        document.getElementById('num').value = "";
        }
        else{
            alert("You have entered "+ var2 + " which has now been stored, thankyou!");
            document.getElementById('num').value = "";
        }
    }

   </script>
```

```
Number: <input type="text" name="numcheck" id="num" />
<button onclick="numcheck()"/> Enter </button>
</body>
</html>
```

I dont know exactly what the question is but I just did this hope it clarifies what ever the  user is looking for.

also `<!-- -->` are html comments if you would like to comment javascript try // or /**/